# Можно ли изменить данный функционал. PHP

Tags: php

Можно ли получить src не только в img, а во всех тегах с атрибутом src?

```
<?php

$txt = 'Lorem Lorem Lorem <img src="path/img1.jpg"/> LoremLoremLoremLorem
LoremLorem Lorem <img src="path/img2.jpg" /> LoremLoremLorem
LoremLoremLorem
LoremLorem <img src="path/img3.jpg" />.';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($txt);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
    var_dump( $node->getAttribute('src') );
}
```

Comment: Ну так обходи все ноды и проверяй есть ли у нода атрибут `src`. Или смотри в сторону xpath.

Comment: Можно получить все элементы таким образом `$dom->getElementsByTagName('*')`, и затем проверять внутри цикла `$element->hasAttribute('src')`, но думаю что должны быть решения получше.

Comment: @Simon Супер, понимаю, что должны быть лучше, но для меня оптимально

Comment: Список тегов, которые могут содержать атрибут src, не так уж и велик. Я бы сделал перечень желаемых узлов и обошел бы их, это всяко лучше, чем обходить все узлы в документе.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать как указали в комментариях:

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('*')
```

и затем проверять внутри цикла

```
$element->hasAttribute('src')
```

---

А есть вариант сразу через `xpath` выбрать все элементы с таким атрибутом:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($txt);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//*[src]') as $node) {
    
}
```

Не уверен до конца, что сработает. Но у [css есть такая опция](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). А парсинг DOM происходит примерно по этому приницпу.

**Note**: Возможно вместо `'//*[src]'` должно быть `'//*[@src]'`

Comment: там по идее просто `//*[@src]/@src` можно чтобы значения сразу получить

Comment: @teran вот это не в курсе